# Why am I getting so many indices when a 2D ndarray is passed into nonzero function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I trying to find out the non-zero elements in a 2D ndarray. When I passed my array into np.nonzero() function, I am getting the same index multiple times.

```
import numpy as np
ar1 = np.array([[4,7,3,0,0,1],[4,1,1,0,1,6]])
items_not_zero = np.nonzero(ar1)
print(items_not_zero)
# (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]))
```

I was expecting to have a tuple with the indices of the non-zero elements just once..

Comment: The 'first array'? `ar1` is only one array.  Look at it.  It's a (2,6) array.  `nonzero` returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension.  You have 9 nonzero terms in `ar1`.

Comment: @hpaulj,I understand that there are 9 items in the array which are non-zero. So if we first look at the 1st dimension (please correct me if that not a dimension!) **[4,7,3,0,0,1]** then in the first item in the returned tuple should be ([0,1,2,5])..isn't it?

Comment: `non_zero` works with the whole array, not row by row.  The first 4 values of the two arrays are [0,0,0,0] and [0,1,2,5].

Answer (score 2):

`np.nonzero` returns an array for each dimension of the array passed in. In your example

```
 (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]))
```

corresponds to the indexes:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 5), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5)]
```

…the first array corresponds to the `[0]` coordinate and the next corresponds to the `[1]` dimension of each tuple.

You can `zip` these together or, as the docs mention you can get a list of tuples with:

```
print(np.transpose(np.nonzero(ar1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should look at the [documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) for `numpy.nonzero`.

Basically, what `nonzero` returns is a tuple of arrays immediately suitable for indexing:

```
ar1[(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]))]
# array([4, 7, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 6])
```

This means that the number of arrays returned is equal to the number of dimensions of your array (e.g. `ar1` is a 2-D array), and each group of numbers on the same position is an index into the original array. For example, the third element of those arrays are 0 and 2 respectively, which means `arr[0][2]` is nonzero.

An easy way to make the result more "human-readable", as the documentation page mentions, is to transpose it:

```
np.transpose(np.nonzero(ar1))
'''
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 5],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5]])
'''
```